# Why is my oval div in CSS put next to the right side wall (border) of my website when I resize or restore it down?

Tags: css, border

I am trying to make space between my oval 'div' and the right wall (border) of my website with margin but it doesn't seem to work.What could be the problem? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <style>
    div.oval1 {
      width: 1460px;
      margin: 80px 0px 30px 30px;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 10%;
      height: 600px;
      border-radius: 1%;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="oval1"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Link of the website: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GQYCSO6PHXZM

Comment: it is not just put against the side, it is overflowing, you create a scrollbar when the width of the page is less than the `width: 1460px` + `margin` given to the div.

Comment: also, you are missing a couple open/closing tags: line 20: `</head>`, line 20: `<body>` line 21: `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

In order to see margin in the right side of an element at least one of the parent elements need to have a definite width.
The width of the parent should be larger than the sum of left side margin, element width and right margin.

Tt is same for the bottom margin, in that case parents height should be larger than the sum of top and bottom margin and element's height.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



  <style>
 
    
    body {
      width: 1520px;
    }
    
    div.oval1 {
      width: 1460px;
      margin: 80px 30px 30px 30px;
      background-color: black;
      opacity: 10%;
      height: 600px;
      border-radius: 1%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="oval1">









</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are the best